# How to group by two conditions and count if ALL rows meet another condition

Tags: r, group-by

I have the following data in this form:

```
Household <- rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4"), each = 3) 
Product <- c(21,21,19,18,21,21,11,11,19,16,16,12) 
Discount <- c(0,1,0,0, 0.5,1,0.5,1,0,0,0,1)

data <- data.frame(Household = Household, Product = Product, Discount = Discount)
```

I would like to count the number of times a household has ALWAYS purchased a product with a discount.

```
Household <- c(2, 3)
Product <- c(21, 11)
result <- data.frame(Household = Household, Product = Product)
```

Thank you very much.

I have tried grouping by household and product and summarising when the discount is >0, but this tells me the individual instances of purchases by households that were bought with a discount. I think the SQL equivalent of "having" would help here according to my queries.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` we could do:

```
library(dplyr)

data |>
  count(Household,
        Product,
        wt = Discount > 0) |>
  filter(n > 1)
```

Or maybe a bit clearer:

```r
library(dplyr)

data |>
  group_by(Household, Product) |>
    filter(Discount > 0) |>
    tally() |>
    filter(n > 1) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Household Product     n
  <chr>       <dbl> <int>
1 2              21     2
2 3              11     2
```

Comment: This removes households that bought a  product only once while the product was discounted (Household 4, Product 12). Not sure if this is desired.

Comment: As far as I can see OP want just `21, 11`

Comment: Thank you very much, I used your second option and it works very well. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Yes it is a bit more useful for my purposes where there have been repeat purchases

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using the `dplyr` package?

I think what you are looking for is something like the base R function `all`. See below

```r
library(dplyr)

result <- data |>
 group_by(Household, Product) |>
 filter(all(Discount != 0)) |>
 select(-Discount) |>
 unique()
```

Comment: This is really helpful thank you, I can see the instances where each of the products were repurchased and it includes where items were only purchased once (but on discount). Appreciate it!